# Does ember-data subsequent find generates XHR every time without caching?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an app built using ember-cli 0.2.5 (which is Ember 1.12.0 and Ember-Data 1.0.0-beta.17).

My models' store.find() always generate XHR request to my backend. I would expect subsequent route accesses to use the store's cache.

I have two routes, router.js is:

`Router.map(function() {
    this.route('rules', {path: '/rules'});
    this.route('users', {path: '/users'});
});`

The routes models are:

`Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return this.store.find('user');
    }
});`

and

`Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return this.store.find('rule');
    }
});`

I am using the RESTAdapter and targeting an apache server which executes a perl cgi. The returned JSON (snippet) is:

`{"rules":[{"canAutoUnblock":1,"creator":"spaling","status":null,"autoUnblockDate":"2015-05-30","createTime":"2015-01-19 19:59:56","privComment":"not private","pubComment":"Port scanning the Library","id":12,"ipaddr":"31.7.59.152"},{"canAutoUnblock":0,"creator":"spaling","status":"delete","autoUnblockDate":null,"createTime":"2015-01-19 19:59:56","privComment":"private","pubComment":"public","id":13,"ipaddr":"31.7.59.160"},`

formatted ...

`{
rules: [
{
canAutoUnblock: 1,
creator: "spaling",
status: null,
autoUnblockDate: "2015-05-30",
createTime: "2015-01-19 19:59:56",
privComment: "not private",
pubComment: "Port scanning the Library",
id: 12,
ipaddr: "31.7.59.152"
},
{
canAutoUnblock: 0,
creator: "spaling",
status: "delete",
autoUnblockDate: null,
createTime: "2015-01-19 19:59:56",
privComment: "private",
pubComment: "public",
id: 13,
ipaddr: "31.7.59.160"
},`

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Barry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior for `find` with no additional parameters.

```
store.find('modelName')
```

This will ask the adapter's findAll method to find the records for the given type, and return a promise that will be resolved once the server returns the values. The promise will resolve into all records of this type present in the store, even if the server only returns a subset of them.

See http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_find

If you want cached records only use

```
store.all('modelName')
```

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_all

Comment: But when I revisit the route is it supposed to be generating another XHR? I thought it would just be returning data from the store's cache? If not, how can I get that behaviour?

Comment: If you want cached records only use `store.all('modelName');`.http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_all

Comment: Thanks, got it. I didn't understand the difference between find and all.

Comment: Stay tuned ember blog this api is going to change (https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/3290)